# What effects not mentioned in its spell description does Greater Restoration cure?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing

The [Greater Restoration spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration) cures many conditions in the worlds of D&D 5e. According to the spell description, these include:

> - One effect that charmed or petrified the target
> - One curse, including the target's attunement to a cursed magic item
> - Any reduction to one of the target's ability scores
> - One effect reducing the target's hit point maximum

However, there are many other conditions scattered throughout the source material that Greater Restoration also cures. One example is [Modify Memory](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/modify-memory):

> A remove curse or **greater restoration spell** cast on the target restores the creature's true memory.

(Note that, although Modify Memory creates a 1-minute charm effect, which can be removed with Greater Restoration, the modified memory itself is not attached to the charm effect, and so this explicit mention of Greater Restoration is important.)

Here's another; the DMG (Chapter 8) states, regarding madness:

> A **greater restoration spell** or more powerful magic is required to rid a character of indefinite madness.

Effectively, the spell's rules are spread out across all the source material; this is problematic for a player who either doesn't own all the source material or doesn't know it well but whose character should know (at least some of) these kinds of limitations. What effects can Greater Restoration cure that are not included in its spell description?

What I'm interested in:

- Any effect that is treatable, according to RAW, with Greater Restoration---this includes spells, but also unique monster effects, item effects, and effects like madness that explicitly mention Greater Restoration as a cure.
- Anything that is cured by Greater Restoration due to the text in the Greater Restoration spell description can be omitted. For example, Charm Person can be removed by Greater Restoration because it induces a charm effect so it needn't be included; similarly, Geas can be removed by Greater Restoration because it creates a charm effect and needn't be included even though its spell description explicitly calls Greater Restoration out.
- Items/monsters/etc. that would not typically appear outside of a specific adventure module needn't be included (e.g., if Strahd von Zarovich had a unique curse ability whose effect could be removed via Greater Restoration, it needn't be included because Strahd is typically unique to the Curse of Strahd module).

Comment: This question asks for the "off-label" uses of *greater restoration*, similar to my question about *wish*: [What are all of the published "off-label" uses of the Wish spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/191721)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll limit this to the core rules for now, and to those that explicitly mention greater restoration:

#### From the PHB

- Contact Other Plane (insanity)
- Modify Memory (as listed by you)
- Feeblemind (ability score reduction)
- Geas (charm, as mentioned)

#### From the DMG

- Wand of Wonder (petrification)
- Artifact Detrimental Abilities (Ability Score Reduction)
- Axe of the Dwarven Lords (curse)
- Indefinite Madness
- Sanity Loss (from failed Sanity Saving throw)

#### From the MM

- Ghost (aging)
- Slaad (destroy control gem)
- Sphinx (aging)

Also, as covered by the spell itself, under Petrification

- Basilisk
- Death Tyrant
- Gorgon
- Medusa

Under Ability score Damage

- Chasme
- Demilich

Under hit point maximum reduction

- Clay Golem
- Night Hag

Comment: While most of these effects are either self-explanatory (petrification, curse), or are organized by you (hit point maximum reduction), it is not obvious what sort of effect is Slaad (gem).  I think the answer would be improved by making this more explicit.